# SQL Ranking N records by one criteria and N records by another and repeat

Tags: sql, loops, ranking

In my table I have 4 columns Id, Type InitialRanking & FinalRanking. Based on certain criteria I’ve managed to apply InitialRanking to the records (1-20). I now need to apply FinalRanking by identifying the top 7 of Type 1 followed by the

[image]

top 3 of Type 2. Then I need to repeat the above until all records have a FinalRanking. My goal would be to achieve the output in the final column of the attached image.

The 7 & 3 will vary over time but for the purposes of this example let’s say they are fixed.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the query you are using.  Also tag with your database.

Comment: Also instead of posting pictures of your data, include formatted text that can be copied and pasted for easier sample creation. Better yet is to include create table and insert statements of your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
       SELECT * FROM(

       ( SELECT ID,DISTINCT TYPE,

          CASE  WHEN TYPE=1 THEN
          ( SELECT TOP 7 INITIALRANK, FINALRANK
            from table where type=1)

         ELSE

          (  SELECT TOP 3 INITIALRANK, FINALRANK
            from table where type=2)

       END CASE 

       FROM TABLE WHERE TYPE IN (1,2)

           )

              UNION

            (    SELECT ID,TYPE,
               INITIALRANK, FINALRANK
                from table where type not in (1,2))

                )
         )
```

Comment: and if it generalised like for type 1 top 7 type2 top3 , type 3 top7 ,type4 top 3...n so on if you meant this then just in the case statement replace `case when type%2!=0 then select top 7 ....where type%2!=0 else select top 3..where type%2=0 `and remove union it will work

Answer (score 0):

A simple (or simplistic) approach to your Final Rank would be the following:

```
row_number() over (partition by type order by initrank) +
case type
     when 1 then (ceil((row_number() over (partition by type order by initrank))/7)-1)*(10-7)
     when 2 then (ceil((row_number() over (partition by type order by initrank))/3)-1)*(10-3)+7
end FinalRank
```

This can be generalized for more than 2 groups for example with three groups of size 7, 3 and 2, the pattern size is 7+3+2=12 the general form is PartitionedRowNum+(Ceil(PartitionedRowNum/GroupSize)-1)*(PaternSize-GroupSize)+Offset where the offset is the sum of the preceding group sizes:

```
row_number() over (partition by type order by initrank) +
case type
     when 1 then (ceil((row_number() over (partition by type order by initrank))/7)-1)*(12-7)
     when 2 then (ceil((row_number() over (partition by type order by initrank))/3)-1)*(12-3)+7
     when 3 then (ceil((row_number() over (partition by type order by initrank))/2)-1)*(12-2)+7+3
end FinalRank
```

Comment: but is the above general as if we could apply to each and every database (use of rownumber() over(partition..))?

Comment: No, not all DBs have analytic functions, let alone some form of the ceiling function (it can also be done with floor or truncate), but for those that do have such functions it will work.  However, if there are a disproportionate number of type 1s to type 2s there will be gaps with this approach.